# Cannot insert layout tag in manifest's activity

Tags: android, android-manifest, picture-in-picture

Do you know why it is not possible for me to add the `layout` tag in manifest's `activity`? I'm trying to add the PIP features in my app and want to configure the manifest as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html#configuring), but when I try to add the `layout` tag, it does not suggest it (only `intent-filter` and `meta-data` tags can be added into `activity`) and it warns me with "Element layout is not allowed here".

I'm using Android Studio 3, buildToolsVersion 26.0.2, compileSdkVersion 25, targetSdkVersion 25 (minSdkVersion is 9 but it should not be a problem).

Comment: Looks like an Android Studio bug.